# Connecting Amana Furnace Pressure Switch

Tags: switch, heating, furnace, pressure, air

Hello fellow DIY'ers,

I had to turn on the heating for the first time this season, our Amana gas furnace didn't stay lit for more than ~7 seconds. I did some research online, ended up cleaning the igniter and also unplugged the pressure switch and cleaned out the vacuum tube that's connected to it. This did indeed solve the issue, furnace stays on!

However, I did not take a note of where the vacuum tube was plugged in, there are 2 nipples on the switch itself, and now I'm questioning if I plugged it back correctly. This seems to be the exact switch in question: https://www.supplyhouse.com/Cleveland-Controls-RSS-495-011-OEM-Air-Pressure-Sensing-Switch-25-1-0-W-C?utm_source=google_ad&utm_medium=pmax&utm_campaign=geo_pmax_test&gclid=Cj0KCQjwpompBhDZARIsAFD_Fp9FxkQgvUl3hDCXUxFqXgIt1ZOz_KuyU3uvaMZKSEw6HWtc3NNpnU4aAjlKEALw_wcB

Here is how it's connected (and working). There are also multiple terminals to hook up, the 2 bottom connectors are labeled as "ON" and the top one is "COM". Could somebody confirm I have this correct ?
Thank you so much!

[image: Switch plugged in correctly ?]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dd6nieRyYa8

Answer (score 0):

I'm questioning whether it's really the correct switch: the linked page at supplyhouse.com says this is a vertical diaphragm switch, but it is installed in a horizontal position. I suppose you could build a different bracket to hold the switch vertically, but first verify that its switch point (0.25" to 1" WC - maybe?) is correct.

Then, just make sure it's working correctly. With the furnace burning, disconnect that gray tube. The switch should operate and the burner should shut down. Re-connect, get the burner going again, and disconnect one of the wires. Again the burner should shut down. If it passes those tests it's probably working correctly.

Comment: That switch is just loosely in there, not connected to anything.

Comment: Greg, I performed those tests and all seems to be working as intended. Thank you.